# Setting in boolean flag in Rust CLI tool using `clap`

Tags: rust, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to have a CLI tool that redacts files in a folder according to some specified regexes.

In debugging, as an example:

```
cargo run -- folder ./tests/test_files -t emails ip -r
```

which means to redact all files in folder path = `./tests/test_files` and `-r` means to do so recursively.

Below is a list of structs that attempted to achieve this:

```
use clap::{Parser, Subcommand, Args};

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
#[clap(author, version, about, name = "raf")]
pub struct Opts {
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    pub cmd: FileOrFolder,
}

#[derive(Debug, Subcommand)]
pub enum FileOrFolder {
    #[clap(name = "folder")]
    Folder(FolderOpts),
    #[clap(name = "file")]
    File(FileOpts),
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
pub struct FolderOpts {
    /// `path` of the directory in which all files should be redacted, e.g. ./tests/test_files
    #[clap(parse(from_os_str), required = true)]
    pub path: std::path::PathBuf,

    /// The type of redaction to be applied to the files, e.g. -t sgNRIC emails
    #[clap(short, long, required = true, multiple_values = true)]
    pub types: Vec<String>,

    #[clap(short, long, required = false, takes_value = false)]
    pub recursive: Option<bool>,
}
```

This is the error that occurs during runtime:

```
Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 45.31s
     Running `target\debug\raf.exe folder ./tests/test_files -t sgNRIC email -r`
error: The argument '--recursive <RECURSIVE>' requires a value but none was supplied

For more information try --help
error: process didn't exit successfully: `target\debug\raf.exe folder ./tests/test_files -t sgNRIC email -r` (exit code: 2)
```

My question is, how do I write the struct `FolderOpts` such that if `-r` is present in as a parameter in the CLI arguments, it is parsed as `.recursive` = `true` and if it is absent, `.recursive` = `false`?

Comment: Try `recursive: bool` and remove `required = false` from it. It should now default to `false` if `-r` is not given.

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert, it works! Just curious, how do you know? Because I'd checked the docs, it is honestly quite difficult to understand.

Comment: I also cannot find this explicitly documented. The closest thing is the mention that `bool` flags are equivalent to `.action(ArgAction::SetTrue)` (https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/index.html#arg-types). I knew this because I've used clap in many projects and this is how I used `bool` flags.

Comment: It's documented in [the tutorial](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_derive/_tutorial/index.html#flags): _Flags can also be switches that can be on/off. This_ […] _is implied when the field is a bool._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bool` options don't need to be wrapped in `Option` to be optional. They are set to `false` by default and `true` if their name is passed as argument. This should work:

```
#[clap(short, long)]
pub recursive: bool,
```

Answer (score 1):

In clap you can set it like this:

```rust
use clap::{ArgAction, Parser};

/// Test
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Clean database
    #[arg(short, long, action(ArgAction::SetTrue))]
    clean: bool,
}
```

or use abbreviations

```rust
use clap::Parser;

/// Test
#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    /// Clean database
    #[arg(short, long, action)]
    clean: bool,
}
```

Cause default action is `SetTrue` in clap [ArgAction](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/enum.ArgAction.html).

```rust
pub enum ArgAction {
    Set,
    Append,
    SetTrue,
    SetFalse,
    Count,
    Help,
    HelpShort,
    HelpLong,
    Version,
}
```

If the user provides the `--clean` parameter, this `args.clean` value will become `true`.